# nestjs context.swithToHttp().getRequest() returns undefined

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I want to create RolesGuard for Graphql

I create Roles decorator like following

```
export const Roles = (...roles: string[]) => SetMetadata('roles', roles);
```

And I create GqlAuthGuard and RolesGuard like following

```
gql-gurad.ts

@Injectable()
export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
    getRequest(context: ExecutionContext){
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        return ctx.getContext().req;
    }
}

role-guard.ts

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
        const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
        if (!roles) {
            return true;
        }
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const user = request.user;

        ...
    }
}
```

but line `const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();` returns undefined.

and i'm using two guards like following

```
@AuthGuard(GqlAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
@Mutation(...)
```

What did I miss??

Comment: Where does the `user` property come from?  In what I'm making I have the concept of an organization instead of a user, but the `.getRequest()` still returns the `user` property but with my organization on it. I mean it works fine, it's just an odd forced naming convention that doesn't apply to me. I'd like to change it if possible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I solved it myself.

```
const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
const user = request.user;

to

const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
const user = ctx.getContext().req.user;
```

i found it from nestjs discord channel.

https://discordapp.com/channels/520622812742811698/520649487924985885

Comment: Another usecase where `context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>()` returns undefined is with websocket. I met the case with a global guard + adding websocket (through graphql). Such guard has to be reimagined for websocket if, for example, relying on HTTP headers.