# How can I use the same RoleGuard for REST and GraphQL?

Tags: rest, graphql, nestjs, guard

I have this problem:
[nestjs context.swithToHttp().getRequest() returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497740/nestjs-context-swithtohttp-getrequest-returns-undefined)

The difference is I need to support GraphQL and REST for my application, but actually, I can't figure out any way to use the same RoleGuard for GraphQL and REST because they have context different.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out it myself

```
    let user: User;

    if (context.getType() === 'http') {
      user = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
    } else if (context.getType<GqlContextType>() === 'graphql') {
      const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      user = ctx.getContext().req.user;
    }
```